# Is there a word for a person who's obsessed with lights?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

I need to know if there exists a word for a person who's obsessed with lights. The formation lights make etc.

Comment: I seriously doubt there's an existing standard term for such people, but it's got to be worth considering [**luciferian**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Luciferian). I know Lucifer is generally considered *The Lord of **Darkness***, but his sobriquet does derive from Latin *light-bringer*, and a lucifer is dated slang for a match, light. Me, I worship Dilbert's [*Phil, God of Insufficient Light*](https://padresteve.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/phil.gif), 'cos I think it's good to have a god with a lighter side.

Comment: [Lighting Designer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighting_designer)

Comment: There is [*photomania*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=sXgbdsaGDKYC&pg=PA313&dq=dictionary+%22photomania%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1_hpVYv1A9CcygT80oDIBg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=dictionary%20%22photomania%22&f=false) for the abnormal craving for light.

Comment: @Christopher: I think that might be what I've always called the ***gaffer***. But I get confused when they start talking about *best boy **electric*** as opposed to *best boy **grip*** (not to mention *key grip*).

Comment: No, but "Photophobia" is a term for a person who has a morbid fear of light.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, From what I understand the 'chief lighting *technician* 'is the *gaffer*, but assume they would light the stage / area as per the design.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I just use photophile. People (especially those who are 'obsessed with lights') usually understand where I'm coming from. I describe a photophile as someone who is 'obsessed with' watts, lumens, efficacy, footcandles, the sun, bulbs, L.E.D.'s (different colors of L.E.D.'s), flashlights/headlamps, lanterns, light displays, refraction (see: prism) just to name a few genres. Someone may only identify with one, some, or all, but may still be a photophile.

Comment: I though a *photophile* was my Pictures directory in Windows.

Comment: ...or someone who can't stay off Instagram.

Comment: Not good. 'Photophile' already has an established definition that this cuts against. The one I guessed. ELU requires standard, not arbitrary, usages.

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't know if there is a word in common use, but the common suffix for a 'lover of' is 'phile'. Some words have been brought into common use that may not have even existed previously. Ie. Japanophile - someone who has a love for all things Japanese.

Therefore using the Latin for light (Lux) you could maybe create a word like **Luxophile** or **Lumophile**, or even **Photophile** if photomania is a craving for light

Comment: Since the suffix *phile* is Greek, it doesn't make sense to use a Latin word like *lux*. Photophile would be appropriate, except that photo is such a commonly used word that photophile will probably be interpreted as a lover of photography. (Indeed that is the definition of photophile on Urban Dictionary).

Comment: As mikeagg says, Greek roots are preferred in compounds that end in *-philia* or *-phobia.* That said, there are a number of established mixed compounds, such as *claustrophobia.*  A more serious problem with *luxophile* is that it doesn't use the proper form of the root. *Lux* is the nominative form. When making a compound, you should remove the nominative suffix *-s* and use just the root *luc-* followed by a linking vowel. Latin roots usually use *-i-* and Greek roots usually use *-o-.* Since this would be mixed, you could use either. So something like *luciphile* would be better.

Comment: '[Y]ou could maybe create a word like' is anathema on ELU, or indeed and SE site, where generally accepted and verifiable practices are required.